# To_char in hibernate join

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any way to achieve the following snippet in Hibernate 3.3?

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
{ @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="to_char(id)", referencedColumnName="product_idnf")) })
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Product productFamily;
```

This is implemented in hibernate 3.5+. But I want to do the same in 3.3.